# AJAX REQUEST WITH IN AJAX REQUEST jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: searchpage,
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        id: id
    },
    success: function(data) {
        var id1 = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            id1 .push({
                 id1 : data[i].id

            });
            $("#printtdownername").text(data[i].fullname);
            $("#printtdownerbday").text(data[i].bday);
            $("#printtdownerage").text(data[i].age);
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'searchpage1',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                id1: JSON.stringify(id1)
            },
            success: function(data) {

            },
            error: function(data) {}
        });

    },
    error: function(data) {

    }
});
```

In my project I need to send an AJAX request on a specific event and when that request is successful I want to send another AJAX request. Right now its working ok since my database is only small.

My question is will this have a negative effect if for example I have a big database. If this is not a good practice how should I deal with this scenario.
I need the id1 from response of first AJAX in order to send the second AJAX.

Comment: The only drawback is that the second ajax won't be fired until the first one completes. so if first one takes a long time to complete, user might browse away / submit forms etc without waiting for the second ajax even to be sent. Other then that that's how i'd do it.

Comment: I think you should do this logic at server and save one request, 2 request is not efficient

Comment: @VolkanUlukut that is what i am thinking right now slow reaction time because of large data. Anyway to make it a bit better in terms of reaction time?

Comment: @Saqueib please enlighten me.

Comment: If you are making first request to only get the `id1` and in second request you are sending same `id1` then you can do this part of logic at backend

Comment: just see your `success` callback, this logic need to be placed on server so it will respond with with actual result, not only with an `id`

Comment: the problem is how to send back the the second set of data. i am returning  json can i send more than 1 json?or need to combine two json for this?

Comment: do not return the json. take the json on server side: searchpage, and manipulate it as you would in :'searchpage1'

Comment: @VolkanUlukut actually i need to return the data from search one. I need to display some data. In addition i need to search another set of data by using an ID from that search result to select again

Comment: send us the complete relevant code. i mean where you use id1, and if you don't send id1 to second ajax, what you are sending etc. cause the code you shared doesn't need a second ajax.

Comment: @VolkanUlukut i only added a few because it is too many personal informations educational background etc.

Comment: we don't need the static data, just replace them with lorem ipsum

Comment: Try to send `fullname`, `bday` in first request along with `id` if its required, and do the all work on server

Answer (score -2):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: searchpage,
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        id: id
    },
    success: function(data) {
        var id1 = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            id1 .push({
                 id1 : data[i].id

            });
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'searchpage1',
              dataType: "json",
              data: {
                id1: JSON.stringify(id1)
              },
              success: function(data) {

              },
              error: function(data) {}
         });

       }


    },
    error: function(data) {

    }
});
```

Try this.
I think this might be helpful to you

here is an working example : [Example](http://urfusion.net/testajax2.php)

for avoid unnecessary requests call that after loop.

Comment: this won't work. id1 is not defined in the context of second ajax.

Comment: @VolkanUlukut: id1 is available for second ajax request because it is within the scope. var `id1 = [];`
ajax request and id both is in same scope of success.

Comment: id1 is supposed to be an array, which is sent after its filled out with values.  what you did is sending id1 for each iteration making tons of unnecessary requests.

Comment: so now you are saying that `id1` is not out of scope for second ajax request, right?

Comment: yes it is in the scope, you messed up with the formatting so i thought you took the second ajax out of the success callback. this answer is still wrong though.

Comment: don't be so fast for comment. check yourself first. and I am agree that it will cause many ajax request. but it will work

Comment: id1 is not defined as it should be for iteration-1 times. which is totally unnecessary. I think you should tell us why you did what you did instead of commenting comments.

Comment: ops problem is not "not working code" its about performance and what you did is just decreasing performance even more.

Comment: check console for results